# Read contents of tar file without unzipping to disk

Tags: go, tar

I have been able to loop through the files in a tar file, but I am stuck on how to read the contents of those files as string. I would like to know how to print the contents of the files as a string?

This is my code below

```
package main

import (
    "archive/tar"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "bytes"
    "compress/gzip"
)

func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("testtar.tar.gz")

    archive, err := gzip.NewReader(file)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("There is a problem with os.Open")
    }
    tr := tar.NewReader(archive)

    for {
        hdr, err := tr.Next()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        fmt.Printf("Contents of %s:\n", hdr.Name)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use the tar.Reader as an io.Reader for each file you want to read.

```
tr := tar.NewReader(r)

// get the next file entry 
h, _ := tr.Next()
```

If you need the whole file as a string:

```
// read the complete content of the file h.Name into the bs []byte
bs, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(tr)

// convert the []byte to a string
s := string(bs)
```

If you need to read line by line, then this would be better:

```
// create a Scanner for reading line by line
s := bufio.NewScanner(tr)

// line reading loop
for s.Scan() {

  // read the current last read line of text
  l := s.Text()

  // ...and do something with l

}

// you should check for error at this point
if s.Err() != nil {
  // handle it
}
```

Comment: This reads, but doesn't return the right type of content all of it is just a slice of type uint8. No real content.

Comment: You can't expect the Reader to know the type. Its your responsibility to handle its content.

Comment: @AJPennster Do you know of any easy way to do the conversions. Am confused as how a slice element does not return a line of string, but yet a int. I don't how to go about the conversion.

Comment: @m.. The content of a file (be it on disk or in a tar file) **is** just a bunch of bytes, there is no more content to it. Please explain the original problem.

Comment: @m.. What type of content are you trying to get?

Comment: @m.. please stop everything you're doing and read https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html

Comment: @PabloLalloni I was trying to get strings from txt files that are packed in a tar file.

Comment: @m.. just one big string for the whole file (see my edited answer) or one string per line of input?

Comment: @PabloLalloni Good, succinct answer. How would you go about line by line data out of the file instead of the whole thing?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I have seen people use `tar.gz` as a makeshift database, so I found it
useful to read the archive into a `fstest.MapFS`:

```
package main

import (
   "archive/tar"
   "compress/gzip"
   "io"
   "os"
   "testing/fstest"
)

func tarGzMemory(source string) (fstest.MapFS, error) {
   file, err := os.Open(source)
   if err != nil { return nil, err }
   defer file.Close()
   gzRead, err := gzip.NewReader(file)
   if err != nil { return nil, err }
   tarRead := tar.NewReader(gzRead)
   files := make(fstest.MapFS)
   for {
      cur, err := tarRead.Next()
      if err == io.EOF { break } else if err != nil { return nil, err }
      if cur.Typeflag != tar.TypeReg { continue }
      data, err := io.ReadAll(tarRead)
      if err != nil { return nil, err }
      files[cur.Name] = &fstest.MapFile{Data: data}
   }
   return files, nil
}
```

Example:

```
package main

func main() {
   m, e := tarGzMemory("mingw64.db.tar.gz")
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   data := m["mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-10.2.0-10/desc"].Data
   print(string(data))
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/testing/fstest

Answer (score -1):

With some help from the official site this is what I had intended previously. Special focus should be turned to the bottom where the conversion from bytes to string is made.

```
package main

import (
    "archive/tar"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "bytes"
    "compress/gzip"
)

func main() {

    file, err := os.Open("testtar.tar.gz")

    archive, err := gzip.NewReader(file)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("There is a problem with os.Open")
    }
    tr := tar.NewReader(archive)

    for {
        hdr, err := tr.Next()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        fmt.Printf("Contents of %s:\n", hdr.Name)

        //Using a bytes buffer is an important part to print the values as a string

        bud := new(bytes.Buffer)
        bud.ReadFrom(tr)
        s := bud.String()
        fmt.Println(s)
        fmt.Println()
    }

}
```

Comment: please check my answer above for an easier way of reading the whole thing to a string