# How to check if file is tar file in GoLang?

Tags: go, tar

I want to implement a program to extract a tar file in GoLang, but before extracting, I want to check if the file is tar file. I am not interested only to check the file extension. And in shell, I can use the following command to do this:

```sh
file AFile.tar
AFile.tar: POSIX tar archive (GNU)
```

But what shoud I do in GoLang?

Comment: Have you made any attempt of your own that you can show?

Comment: finally i use shell to do this:

Answer (score 4):

I would guess you could use the `archive/tar` package. Here's an untested example:

```
tr := tar.NewReader(&buf)
hdr, err := tr.Next()
if err != nil {
  // not a tar file...
}
```

Calling `tr.Next()` should be cheap as it only examines a header. For a valid tar file, the header will check out...

Answer (score 0):

```
import (
    "archive/tar"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "errors"
)

// ExtractTar extract tar
func ExtractTar(stream io.Reader, name string) error {
    tarReader := tar.NewReader(stream)

    for true {
        header, err := tarReader.Next()

        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }

        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("extract tar next failed: %w", err)
        }

        switch header.Typeflag {
        case tar.TypeDir:
            if err := os.Mkdir(header.Name, 0750); err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("extract tar mkdir: %w", err)
            }
        case tar.TypeReg:
            outFile, err := os.Create(name)
            if err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("extract tar create: %w", err)

            }
            defer outFile.Close()
            if _, err := io.Copy(outFile, tarReader); err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("extract tar copy failed: %w", err)
            }
        default:
            return errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("extract tar: unknown type: %v in %s", header.Typeflag, header.Name))
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: Heavily inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57640231/3266847)? Even retained typos like "uknown". And why is it still called `ExtractTarGz`, but doesn't handle `.gz` files?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i use shell in go to do this:

```sh
shell := fmt.Sprintf(`
        uncompress_if_necessary(){
          local FILE=$1
          result=$(file $FILE | grep 'gzip compressed data')
          [[ -z $result ]] && {
            return
          }
          echo "$FILE is a gzip compressed file, need to uncompress"
          tar -zxvf $FILE
        } && cd %s && uncompress_if_necessary %s >> %s
    `, dirPath, filePath, taskLogFilePath)
cmd := exec.Command("/bin/bash", "-c", shell)
return cmd.Run()
```

Comment: If you actually want to do it in go you can use a list of file signatures to figure out if it is actually a tar file (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) - this is what `file` does. This is however only a heuristic that may fail so you will need to actually try to unpack it using e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42564146/read-contents-of-tar-file-without-unzipping-to-disk and handle to be sure.

Comment: Yeah, Using list of file signatures to check the file type is the better way. thank u, i'll try this